# Excess JLabels not being removed from frame after RemoveAll()

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have a button that finds available timeslots for specific dates and displays them. However, when I run this more than one its fails to remove the previous JLabels if the amount of timeslots are less than the previous results.

How would I go about removing these excess labels every time?

Thanks in advance for help!

```
timeCheck.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    farRightSidePanel.removeAll();

                    String selectedDoctor = doctorsDropdown.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    List<String> times = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(allAppointmentTimes));
                    List<String> takenAppointmentTimes = db.freeTimeslotsDB(
                            datePicker.getJFormattedTextField().getText(),
                            selectedDoctor.substring(selectedDoctor.length() - 2));

                    times.removeIf(t -> takenAppointmentTimes.contains(t));

                    for (String time : times) {
                        farRightSidePanel.add(new JLabel(time));
                        farRightSidePanel.revalidate();
                    }

                } catch (SQLException e1) {

                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

[image: All available appointments]

[image: Problem with labels]
[image: 2 appointments unavailable]

Answer (score 0):

Repainting the frame seems to have fixed the problem.

```
timeCheck.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    farRightSidePanel.removeAll();

                    String selectedDoctor = doctorsDropdown.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    List<String> times = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(allAppointmentTimes));
                    List<String> takenAppointmentTimes = db.freeTimeslotsDB(
                            datePicker.getJFormattedTextField().getText(),
                            selectedDoctor.substring(selectedDoctor.length() - 2));

                    times.removeIf(t -> takenAppointmentTimes.contains(t));

                    for (String time : times) {
                        farRightSidePanel.add(new JLabel(time));
                        farRightSidePanel.revalidate();
                        farRightSidePanel.repaint();
                    }

                } catch (SQLException e1) {

                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```